# How do you clean up an in-memory core data instance between test runs?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have some code that I use to generate an in-memory CoreData instance

```swift
class CoreDataContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    init(name: String, mom: NSManagedObjectModel, inMemory: Bool = false) {
        super.init(name: name, managedObjectModel: mom)
        configureDefaults(inMemory)
    }
    private func configureDefaults(_ inMemory: Bool = false) {
        if let storeDescription = persistentStoreDescriptions.first {
            storeDescription.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = true
            if inMemory {
                storeDescription.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
                storeDescription.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I retrieve the container like this before every `setUp()` call:

```swift
static func persistentContainer(mom: NSManagedObjectModel) -> CoreDataContainer {
    return CoreDataContainer(name: "Model", mom: mom, inMemory: true)
}
```

However, it doesn't seem like it's being cleared. Is there something special that I need to do to clear the data synchronously between each run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your CoreDataContainer as a property in your test class

```
var coreDataContainer: CoreDataContainer!
```

and then initialize it in setUpWithError so that a new instance is created for each test

```
func setUpWithError() throws {
    coreDataContainer = …
 }
```

You should also rewrite CoreDataContainer so that you have an init that only takes the inMemory argument and nothing else. Take a look at the PersistenceController that is included if you create a new Core Data project in Xcode.

Comment: Got it is, the `static` part making the test cases reuse the Container?

Comment: If you are talking about the static func then no, this has nothing to do with it.